# copying bytes32 values from map to array

Tags: solidity, arrays, mapping, logs, bytes32

I am trying to copy stored values from a map to an array. I have the following code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract test {

event LogTest(
    bytes32[5] a
); 

bytes32[5]  arr;    
mapping (uint=>bytes32) attr;

//function that stores values and copies them to array which is returned
function attributes() internal returns(bytes32[5]){
    bytes32[5] x;
    attr[0] = "0x0"; attr[1] = "0x1"; attr[2] = "0x2"; attr[3] = "0x3"; attr[4] = "0x4";

    for(uint i=0;i<5;i++){
        x[i] = attr[i];
    }
    return(x);
}

//function that retrieves stored values and prints them in log
function copy() public {
    arr = attributes();
    LogTest(arr);
}    

}
```

For some reason I am not getting the correct values copied. I am getting something that looks like this:

```
"event": "LogTest",
        "args": {
            "0": [
                "0x3078300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "0x3078310000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "0x3078320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "0x3078330000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "0x3078340000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
```

1. What am I doing wrong? Are the values not even permanently stored in the `attributes()` function?
2. Is there a better way to do this than store in a map and copy into an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. What am I doing wrong? Are the values not even permanently stored in the attributes() function?

You are saving the byte representation of the word 0x0, 0x1 etc do: `attr[0]=0x0` instead of `attr[0]="0x0"` (ommit the quotes). That is all.

> 2. Is there a better way to do this than store in a map and copy into an array?

This depends on what you are doing. You can save directly on the array.

Hope this helps.